# is there a fix for mouse going off the edge of the screen?

Tags: ubuntu-studio, multiple-monitors

2 monitors both 1920x1080. Didn't happen in Linux Mint 17, Does in Ubuntu Studio 16.04 . Thought I was going blind, when the cursor disappeared and I couldn't find it!

Set the mouse-cursor red and large and watched it going off right side and bottom of the screen.

Good news, I now know to move the mouse up and to the left to spot movement. 
Bad news, application windows can be moved into this (apparently) imaginary space on left and right of screen to the extent that the mouse allows and down movements of the mouse alone do not move to another workspace, though when dragging an application it does.

BTW: I tried changing the resolution in Settings-Manager>Display and it still happened.

Comment: Not quite sure about the drifting cursor part of the issue. Was that the same hardware that you used or different in Mint  ? As for bringing the mouse back, well, it is possible to have a script that will make cursor jump back to the center of the screen, but that's more of a "treating symptomps, not a disease" type of thing

Answer (score 1):

I was checking out the post as I had the same issue with the mouse going off the right hand side of the screen and when trying to use the scroll on the right and side was awkward!

When I went to Preferences > Display settings I found the screen had two parts! i.e. two rectangle squares showing two screens. I re-checked the additional drivers, this time for some reason 4 different nVidea drivers appeared. They never showed until today in the additional driver section. Anyway to cut a long story short I selected nVidea Binary Proprietary tested driver (not the legacy one) and restarted the computer. Bingo the mouse cursor never leaves the edge of the screen and now only one screen appears Preferences > Display settings.

I hope this helps :D

Comment: I wonder if you can you drag the mouse pointer off the bottom of the screen as my answer illustrates?

Comment: This was my problem (two screens despite only having one), but I suspect in general the problem can be any multitude of things.

Answer (score 1):

### Building a better Mouse Trap

My mouse pointer can also move off the edge of the screen. It's never really bothered me. Even in when the mouse pointer is on the screen there are times I can't seen it so I changed the color to red. For even greater ability to locate the mouse pointer, even when it is moved off the screen, as the `.gif` below shows, you can reveal the mouse pointer by tapping and releasing the <kbd>Control</kbd> key:

[image: mouse off screen.gif]

To enable the mouse pointer locating feature use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing settings-> display -> single display. it fixed things for me.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the problem but for some strange reason, it got resolved 'accidentally' by going to system settings > display > rotation (where accidentally rotated screen by 180 degrees then reverted to 'normal' --and hey presto!)